# Blinding other audio inputs with opentok stream

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to create an audio only chat using OpenTok WebRTC. There will be only 1 publisher. I would like the publisher to be able to upload a music file, start speaking, and have the music and his voice published into the opentok session. Is it possible with OpenTok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to blend music and microphone output and publish it using OpenTok, since OpenTok only receives input for publishing from the mic or a webcam. One thing you could do is play the uploaded file on the site as an audio file, and everyone will be able to hear the file along with the microphone input from OpenTok's stream.

To publish audio only using OpenTok, you can set `publishVideo` to false when you initialize the Publisher. Documentation [here](http://opentok.com/opentok/webrtc/docs/js/reference/TB.html#initPublisher).